# Ripple Effect Directive is full screen instead of only on the element

Tags: angular

I wanted to have the material design ripple effect on my buttons and links.

Searching online I found [ng2-ripple-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ripple-directive) on npm with a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tsm91/7a91717735f72b0b792b44b49b5c61c3) on GitHub of the directive.

Unfortunately, this does not work out of the box, so I modified it and included a module so that I could import it into my app.

It half works as when you click you get a ripple effect but not just on the button, it is full screen.

I have fiddled with the css and with the directive without success. Could anyone assist?

ripple-effect.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as htmlElementStringify from 'html-element-stringify';


@Directive({
    selector: 'button[appRipple], a[appRipple]'
})

export class RippleEffectDirective {
    isRippling = false;
    @Input() appRipple = '#fff';
    @HostBinding('class.ripple') public ripple = 'true';
    @HostBinding('style.position') public position = '"relative"';
    @HostBinding('style.outline') public outline = '"none"';
    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(evt: MouseEvent) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        if (this.isRippling) {
            return;
        }

        this.isRippling = true;

        const button: any = evt.target;
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const xPos = evt.pageX - button.offsetLeft;
        const yPos = evt.pageY - button.offsetTop;

        div.classList.add('ripple-effect');
        div.style.height = button.clientHeight;
        div.style.width = button.clientHeight;
        div.style.top = (yPos - (button.clientHeight / 2)) + 'px';
        div.style.left = (xPos - (button.clientWidth / 2)) + 'px';
        div.style.background = this.appRipple;

        button.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlElementStringify(div));

        window.setTimeout(() => {
            button.removeChild(button.querySelector('.ripple-effect'));
            this.isRippling = false;
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

ripple-effect.directive.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RippleEffectDirective } from './ripple-effect.directive';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [RippleEffectDirective],
    exports: [RippleEffectDirective],
})

export class RippleEffectDirectiveModule {

    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: RippleEffectDirectiveModule,
            providers: [],
        };
    }
}
```

ripple-effect.css

```
.ripple {
   overflow: hidden;
}

.ripple .ripple-effect {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    animation-name: ripple-animation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes ripple-animation {
    from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.4;
    }
    to {
    transform: scale(100);
    opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still like to get this working via a directive however due to agitation I continued my search and was able to accomplish the ripple effect just with CSS thanks to [CodeBurst](https://codeburst.io/create-a-material-design-ripple-effect-without-js-9d3cbee25b3e).
I now have my desired ripple effect with just CSS.
Hopefully, someone else may find this useful.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and Angular 6.

Just chuck the below into your root styles.css and add the "ripple" class to your buttons:

```
.ripple:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #555 10%, transparent 10.01%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    transform: scale(10, 10);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform .5s,
    opacity 1s;
} 

.ripple:active:after {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: .3;
    transition: 0s;
}
```